# Start an application with JScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to start an application using JScript?

Comment: ...And this application should start from?

Comment: Which environment is hosting your JScript?  IE, ASP, WSH?

Comment: In fact I might not have been quite clear. I want to run an application, say Notepas.exe, from an ASP.NET page using JScript

Comment: Do you want the code to run in the ASP on the server or in the HTML on the browser?

Comment: I want this to start client side

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like:

```
WSH = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WSH.run("notepad.exe");
```

Comment: I just tried that and it does nothing in IE. When I try it in Firefox with FireBug, it says: ActiveXObject is not defined

Comment: +1 : but it only works on IE but i guess it is the Olivier intent

Comment: @Olivier : In IE, ActiveX should be enabled

Comment: That looks like it is supposed to run on Windows Scripting Host, not in a browser. (If someone is asking specifically for JScript that is where I'd assume they were aiming)

Comment: @David exact, he asked about JScript, not Javascript.

Comment: JavaScript and JScript are the same language (ECMAScript). Microsoft uses 'JScript' because Sun owned the JavaScript trademark, now owned by Oracle.

Comment: In general, when someone discusses the practical issues of writing JavaScript they are also talking about JScript. When discussing JScript, it seems to be more frequently in MS specific environments — WSH, ASP Classic, etc.

Comment: @Chris Of course. I meant the kind you use in windows scripting. To be fair it has a few differences, like conditional compilation, but I see your point, they follow mostly the same standard.

Answer (score 1):

To launch an executable from [Windows Scripting Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) using [JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yek4tbz0%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), create a file with the `.js` extension and add this code:

```
var shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.Run("calc.exe");
```

Double click the file's icon to execute and launch the application.